# Tag search should be case-insensitive in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I focus a text input box, I start typing in upper case by default. The tag search will not yield any results in that case.

I'm referring to the tag search when posting a question.

To reproduce (on a [Nexus 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_4)):

1. Press the "New question" icon on the top action bar.
2. In case you have a saved draft, discard it.
3. Focus on the *Tags* text input, by touching it.
4. Type an upper-case `A`.
5. No results will appear.

Comment: Okay. Then I guess it's a bug that it's not working for me?

Comment: Just to be sure: you mean the tag editor, when posting a new question or  editing tags of existing question?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn't clear. Question updated

Comment: Well, think it's a bug as anywhere else case doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you post repro steps? I'm not able to recreate this when I search for "Android" and "android" on SO, in both cases I get the same exact results.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi: Done

Comment: Bah that's what I get for not reading your edit, I thought you meant question searches, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.61 coming out later tonight.